# Problem sending/storing session cookie with Vue Axios (CORS)

Tags: vue.js, flask, axios, cors, flask-cors

I cant for some reason store the session cookie from my Flask-backend (port 5000) and send it as credentials from my Vue-frontend (port 8082) via Axios. I create a global axios on the frontend, then login to get the session cookie, and then try to do a request requiring authentication. I see that the cookie gets with response from /login but when next request gets made it doesnt contain it, resulting in 401. The requests work fine with Postman so I assume the problem lies with CORS somehow preventing credentials from being sent.

main.js (setting global instance of Axios)

```
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

auth.js (Vuex module for logging in, and getting cookie)

```
this._vm.$http.post(backendUrl+'/api/login', {
  email: formEmail,
  password: formPassword,
   headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  router.push('profile');
  commit(types.UPDATE_AUTH_SIGN_USER_SUCCESS, response)
  commit(types.UPDATE_AUTH_FORM_PASSWORD, '')
  commit(types.UPDATE_AUTH_FORM_EMAIL, '')
  commit(types.RESET_APP_LOADING)
})
```

Profile.Vue (request requiring session cookie auth which doesnt work, 401)

```
  this.$http.get(backendUrl+'/api/user/gdpr/fetch', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.data == 0) {
      context.dialogGDPR = true;
    }
    context.$store.commit(types.UPDATE_APP_IS_LOADING, false)
  })
```

For the Flask-backend i activate CORS using the following:

app.py

```
CORS(app, origins='http://127.0.0.1:8082', supports_credentials=True)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```

and this for each defined request:

```
@cross_origin(origins='http://127.0.0.1:8082', supports_credentials=True)
```

Comment: Can you see the cookie being set and updated in the Application Tab?
Also did you try creating an instance and adding that to prototype instead of the full axios object, like so.
```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true
})
Vue.prototype.$http = instance;
```

Comment: @HimanshuPant I dont understand how to use Application Tab, but I checked Storage tab and there was no cookies there. I tried using instance like you proposed but still got 401 and no session cookie.

Comment: I wrote an FAQ entry about using cookies with CORS [here](https://cors-errors.info/faq#cdc8), which may help you to find the problem. There's also a header checker at the same site that can check whether your response headers are setting the cookie correctly for CORS. If that doesn't help... 1. Could you check for any console errors/warnings and included them in the question? 2. Could you state the exact browser versions you've tested in? 3. Could you post the response headers for the login request, especially those related to cookies and CORS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's happening. You send a post request to login, your server creates a session and sets a cookie on the client, but in your case the client is not the browser but the xhr object(created by axios) which will soon be wiped out, as a result your browser does not know about the session thus it does not save the sessionId therefore there are no credentials to send along with future requests.
To solve this you have the following options.

1. Try to submit your form as is, without using axios or any javascript. Set `method="post"` and `action="<url_to_login_endpoint>` attributes on your form and let it go nuts. Your submission will be handled by the browser and it will save the sessionID.
2. Look into token based authentication for your backend(I don't know flask so I don't know how that would work), this would be a complete SPA and stateless solution.

I don't know the business logic and constraints but I would suggest setting up Token Auth, as I think that is ideal and more secure but if you're just hacking it together take option 1

Comment: I think session cookie should work with axios somehow, why else would it have the withCredentials option? It seems strange that axios wouldnt have a solution for this.

Comment: The withCredentials is the flag used to send existing session auth cookies along, not to set those cookies. It's not really axios but xhr

Answer (score 1):

So in Vue on front-end you need to set the parameter `withCredentials` `true`
when using axios `axios.get("http://localhost:8081/shop/hello",{withCredentials:true})`

On your server-side API you need to enable CORS and Add header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to the HttpResponse like so `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true`

The thing about Cookies being set over CORS is that they need to be properly created by the browser using the `Set-Cookie` header attributes, you need to add all the attributes else it wont be created.
I had the same problem when creating my Vue.js & Spring-Boot application.

This is how I created my Cookie server side in Java, but you can create it manually or in whatever language you are using,

So problem can happen with the browser not creating the Cookie properly if the `Set-Cookie` header does not have attributes set or is invalid, at least that is what I figured out in this short amount of time, but it worked for me.
I hope this helps.

```
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie("NewRandomCookie",UUID.randomUUID());
 cookie.setPath("/");
 cookie.setMaxAge(3600);
 c.setSecure(false);
 c.setHttpOnly(true);
 cookie.setDomain("localhost");
 
 servletResponse.addCookie(c);
```

This is my server Response Header so you can see how it looks in the browser, im using Chrome here. I think all the attributes you see are required here, also cookie wont be set if you set attribute "Secure" and you need to set the site domain so you can access the cookie after.

```
 Request Header

 Request URL: http://localhost:8081/shop/hello
 Request Method: GET
 Status Code: 200 
 Remote Address: [::1]:8081
 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

 Response Header

 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Type: application/json
 Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 23:10:30 GMT
 Keep-Alive: timeout=60
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6D1C6D23F775A1F650842E55AC0A6E3C; Path=/; HttpOnly
 ->
 Set-Cookie: NewRandomCookie=0fdeba77-072d-4a87-9bc3-f041b2ef138a; Max- 
 Age=3600; Expires=True, 10-Nov-2020 23:47:32 GMT; Domain=localhost; Path=/; 
 HttpOnly;
 <-
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Vary: Origin
 Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
 Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

Comment: cookie.setDomain("localhost") in spring server solve my problem. thanks